# Using a dataframe within multiple class functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, class

I am having trouble understanding classes and how they work. I want the class to read the csv s3 file and then be able to use that csv file to refence in different functions within the class. Is it possible to do so?

```
class solar_model:

    def __init__(self,utility,charge_type):
        self.utility = utility
        self.charge_type = charge_type
        self.rate_df = pd.read_csv('s3_data')

    def input_rate_data(self):
        self.utility = self.rate_df.loc['TDSP']
        self.charge_type = self.rate_df.loc['Class']


new_model = solar_model('CNP', 'Resi')
new_model.input_rate_data()
```

Error:

```
KeyError: 'TDSP'
 def input_rate_data(self): from this line
self.utility = self.rate_df.loc['TDSP']
```

Comment: See [DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) docs where you are attempting to return a single row whose index (*not* column) is named `TDSP`. Confirm the CSV data: `print(self.rate_df.index)`.